# how to instantiate a viewController at the end of an animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, uigesturerecognizer

i have this UIGestureRecognizer that nests an animation in its function, and at the end of that function, I would want to instantiate a viewController.. What is the correct way to accomplish this? here is my code as it is:

```
func longPress(gesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
        {
            oldbounds = self.imageView.bounds

            let bounds = self.imageView.bounds
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.imageView.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + 40, height: bounds.size.height + 40)
            }, completion: nil)

            println("user pressed on image")
        }
        else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
        {
            gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
        }
        else
        {
            let bounds = self.imageView.bounds
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                self.imageView.bounds = self.oldbounds
            })

            println("user release on image")
        }
    }
```

Im guessing the code should be in the completion portion of the animation in the first `gesture.state` condition, however I do not know the correct code implementation to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView.animateWithDuration` has a `completion` `block`. This is where you would put code in to run after the animations are done; your code to initiate a `viewController` for example would go there.

**Example**

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    //Do animation stuff here 
}, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
   //Create your view controller here and show on screen
})
```

Comment: yes i understand that but how do i implement it correctly

Comment: can you provide an example using my code above on how I would correctly implement a viewController instantiation in the animation completion block

Comment: I've added an example for you.

Answer (score 2):

The objective C code for instantiating a VC after a default UIView Animation block would be as follows

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    //animation code here
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardIdentifier"]; // storyboard identifier is set for a VC in the storyboard in its attribute inspector
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];//pushing the VC in the navigation controller.
}];
```

Swift

```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
// your animation code here
  }, completion: { finished in
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  })
```

I guess something like this

Comment: i tagged swift, not obj c :(

Comment: Edited and i posted the Swift method where you would implement this.

Comment: Posted the whole code, although i dont know swift that well but i think its something like this.